# Why is get() slow in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a basic multiprocessing class which takes some parameters and sends them off to a worker:

```
class Multi(object):
    def __init__(self, pool_parameters, pool_size):
        self.pool_parameters = pool_parameters  # Parameters in a tuple
        self.pool_size = pool_size
        self.pool = mp.Pool(self.pool_size)
        self.results = \
            [self.pool.apply_async(worker, args=((self.pool_parameters[i]),),)
                for i in range(self.pool_size)]
        time1 = time.time()
        self.output = [r.get() for r in self.results]  # Output objects in here
        print time.time() - time1

def worker(*args):
    # Do stuff
    return stuff
```

However the r.get() line seems to take ages. If I have a pool_size of 1, the worker returns its result in 0.1 seconds, but the r.get() line takes another 1.35 seconds. Why does it take so long, especially if only one process is started?

EDIT: For a single process and using the worker to return a single None value, the self.output line still takes 1.3 seconds on my system (using time.time() to time that line)

EDIT2: Sorry, I found the problem and I dont think it is to do with multiprocessing. The problem seems to come from importing various other modules. When I got rid my imports the time was 0.1 seconds. No idea why though...

Comment: How big is the object you're returning from `worker`? Also, how are you measuring how long it takes for the `get` call to run?

Comment: It wraps an image file and a csv file, so its about 8 mb currently. But eventually it should be 250 mb. I was using time.time() either side of the self.output line. Calling the worker() outside of the class is 0.1 s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing poor performance because you're sending a large object between the processes. Pickling the object in the child, sending those bytes between processes, and then unpickling them in parent, takes a non-trivial amount of time. This is one of the reasons the best practices for `multiprocessing` suggests [avoiding large amounts of shared state](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#all-platforms):

> **Avoid shared state**
>
> As far as possible one should try to avoid shifting large amounts of
>   data between processes.

You'll probably be able to isolate this behavior if you call `pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(obj))` on your object. I would expect it to take almost as long as the `get()` call.

Comment: Ahha objects get pickled, this makes sense! If I delete the parts of the object which contain references to the image file then this should speed things up?

Comment: @kezzos Yes, the smaller the return value of `worker`, the faster `get` should be.

Comment: Returning 'None' from the worker still results in 1.3 seconds for get() call. Is this overhead from using multiprocessing?

Comment: @kezzos How are you measuring that? Can you provide a complete example? I can't say I've ever noticed that much overhead before.

Comment: you should be comparing this to how long it takes without using multiprocessing.