# multiprocessing .get() method much slower than .map_async()

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm parallelising the solution to an IVP for a given range of parameter values. The solving of multiple IVPs using `multiprocessing.map_async()` is fast, but obtaining the results from the pool using the `.get()` method is approximately 1000x slower.

```python
class paralell_class:
    def __init__(self, params, times, method, bounds, solver):
        self.params=params
        self.times=times
        self.method=method
        self.bounds=bounds
        self.solver=solver
    def paralell_simulate(self, weight_val_entry):
        self.sim_params=copy.deepcopy(self.params)
        for i in range(len(weight_val_entry[0])):
            self.sim_params[weight_val_entry[0][i]]=weight_val_entry[1][i]
        time_series=self.solver(self.sim_params, self.times, self.method,-1, self.bounds)
        time_series=np.multiply(time_series, weight_val_entry[2])
        return (time_series)
    def paralell_dispersion(self, weight_list):
        p = mp.Pool(4)
        start=time.time()
        sc = p.map_async(self,  [weight for weight in weight_list])
        print "Simulation time" + str(time.time()-start)+" s"
        start=time.time()
        results=sc.get()
        print ".get() time" +str(time.time()-start)+" s"
        p.close()
        start=time.time()
        disped_time=np.sum(results, axis=0)
        return disped_time
    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.paralell_simulate(x)
```

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27001181/why-is-get-slow-in-multiprocessing), it's suggested that the size of the array that is slowing down the method. However, increasing the time interval for the solver (i.e. less data) doesn't change the time much:

With the full time-series (5000 time points, 20 simulations)

```
"Simulation time 0.000575065612793 s"
".get() time 0.877493143082 s"
```

When the full time-series is reduced to 500 time points (20 simulations)

```
"Simulation time 0.000617027282715 s"
".get() time 0.950036048889 s"
```

If we decrease the number of simulations, we see a speed increase
(5000 time points, 10 simulations)

```
"Simulation time 0.000108003616333 s"
".get() time 0.239893913269 s"
```

Is this expected behaviour from the multiprocessing module?

Comment: When `.map_async()` returns, you're only getting a result object which represents a handle to access the results once they're done. So, when you call `.get()` immediately after, it has to wait for the calculations to complete. If you used `.map()` you'd see all the processing time is in that call since `.map()` blocks until the results are ready, same as calling `.get()`.
So, yes, expected behaviour.

Comment: Drat, thanks for the quick reply. Would you anticipate any speed up from paralellisation of the function in C/C++? Or is python-multiprocessing about as good as you can get?

Comment: Really hard to say without knowing what's happening in `solver()`. I'd run a single process, single weight run of `paralell_simulate()` and see what's taking time. If all the time is in `np.multiply()` you're not going to improve on that, if it's all in `solver()` maybe that could be improved.